# dl and span tag in one line

Tags: html, css

I have the code like this

```
<div>
<span>This is text</span>
<span>
    <dl>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select category</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<span class="value">Cat1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<span class="value">Cat2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</span>
</div>
```

The output I want is in one line like this.

This is text {Please Select Category dropdownbox}

Currently, the problem i got is, it became two line.

How can i get it into one line ? Please kindly help me with it. Thanks.

Comment: Span elements may not contain dl elements, browsers may error correct by closing the span as the dl starts. I **very** strongly urge you to fix the markup structure ( http://validator.w3.org/ ) before worrying about the presentation of it.

Answer (score 2):

In the CSS:

```
dl, dd, dt { display: inline; }
```

But you probably won't like the result. Why do you use a definition list anyway? Just use spans and the `UL`.

Comment: yea, actually, i want to use this dropdown box, that's why http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

it's using definition list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.. in your CSS stylesheet, add:

```
dt {width: 100px; text-align:right; float:left; clear:left; line-height: 22px; padding-right: 3px;}
dd {margin-left: 100px; line-height: 22px;}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it doesn't work. output is like this

http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/5746/outputspanfloat1.jpg

can you help me to solve again ? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question. There are some other answers here  now which will work - please check them.

Answer (score 0):

Change the second line of your code:

```
<span style="float: left">This is text</span>
```

Edit:

Change your code to:

```
<div style="float: left;">This is text</div>
<div style="margin-left: 80px;">
    <dl>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select category</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<span class="value">Cat1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<span class="value">Cat2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked. but output is like this

http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/8526/outputspanfloat.jpg

I want to have space between This is text and Select Category, how can i do ? Thanks much for helping.

Comment: <span style="float: left">This is text&nbsp;</span>

Comment: it's only move the Select Category text, not the entire definition list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting `max-width` style attribute can help here. Set it to a value that can hold the whole sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a `label` element:

```
<div>
    <label>This is text</label>
    <dl>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select category</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<span class="value">Cat1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<span class="value">Cat2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

along with

```
label,dl
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Because the label element describes the purpose of a form control, and there is no form control here. (Of course, there isn't a list of definitions either…)

Comment: Actually, Isaveit says that he/she is using a form control, albeit a jquery created one. This is the one he/she was talking about: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: /me pokes at the demo. What a disgustingly inaccessible mess.

Answer (score -2):

There is always the possibility to use a table.

```
<div>
<table><tr><td  valign=top >
<span><dl>This is text</span>
</td><td width=15 >&nbsp;</td><td   valign=top  >
<span>
    <dl>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>Please select category</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Brazil<span class="value">Cat1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">France<span class="value">Cat2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</span>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Hey, I know it's not best looking solution, but it does the job.

Comment: great, i totally forgot that fact! Thanks. I got it working now !